# Conflito com o prototype

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento

Estou com uma dúvida que ta acabando com minhas noites.... eu utilizo o magento versão 1.9.... mais quando instalei o modulo `ecomdev` para fazer o calculo de frete na pagina do produto ele me informa um erro ao clicar em calcular frete...

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

---

```
 return elements.inject(initial, function(result, element) {
      if (!element.disabled && element.name) {
        key = element.name; value = $(element).getValue();
        if (value != null && element.type != 'file' && (element.type != 'submit' || (!submitted &&
            submit !== false && (!submit || key == submit) && (submitted = true)))) {
          result = accumulator(result, key, value);
        }
      }
      return result;
    });
  }
};
```

o erro e informado no trecho `key = element.name; value = $(element).getValue();`

Comment: Não dá pra dizer onde no código está o problema só olhando a mensagem de erro, você precisa [edit] a pergunta e dar mais contexto. E quando você fala em "prototype", está falando da biblioteca ou da propriedade das funções construtoras?

Comment: o erro e informado no trecho "key = element.name; value = $(element).getValue();"

Comment: Esse `$(element).getValue();` está estranho. Você possui jQuery na página?

Comment: @Lucas ele está a usar a biblioteca [prototype](http://prototypejs.org/).

Comment: Estou mandando um print da pagina com o erro http://sunsetimports.net.br/data/erro-prototype.PNG

Comment: estou mandando um print da pagina com o erro [link]|(http://sunsetimports.net.br/data/erro-prototype.PNG) **negrito**

Comment: @AlexProenca o que te dá `console.log(element, $(element));` dentro dessa função, na linha antes do erro (dentro do `if`)?

Comment: Ele colocou a tag `jQuery`, suponho que o o jquery esteja conflitando com o prototype, ou algo assim.

Comment: ele me da função anonima, ele nao reconhece o comando enviado do modulo, mai o que e mais estranho Sergio, e que funcionava antes parou depois que atualizei o magento, ate tentei pegar o arquivo antigo do prototype.js e jogar nesse novo mais mesmo assim ele me informa o mesmo erro

Comment: Pois, agora o problema é saber onde usar `$`(do prototype) e onde mudar o `$` para `jQuery`. -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/1401394/2256325

Comment: Nossa e eu sou novo na area... tou apanhando a 2 dias com isso,estou ate sonhando com esse erro kkkk isso no pouco tempo que durmo pois meu chefe esta me cobrando demais o conserto desse erro :(

Answer (score 1):

O [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org/) e o [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) usam ambos a variável `$` e estão a sobrepôr-se. Acho que no teu caso estás a carregar o jQuery depois do Prototype.

A solução é colocares o *jQuery* em modo de não conflito e usar `jQuery` em vez de `$`.

Sugiro na head da página teres assim:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.2.0/prototype.js"></script>
```

Dessa maneira libertas o *dolar* para o *Prototype*. Se continuares a ter erros tens de ir rever o código e mudar os *dolares* que estão em código *jQuery* para `$j(etc...)`.

Se não souberes como... pergunta aqui. Mas vais ter de disponibilizar o código, ou um link para a página.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica vou fazer aqui e mais tarde posto o resultados ... Obrigado pela força Sergio